# SQL Multipolygon void where it overlaps

Tags: sql, geospatial

I have a polygon WKT and turning it into a geography and am presented with two polgyons, but where they overlap there is a void.

I am trying to find markers that exist in any polygon in the string (lat long intersects). The issue is that this void that is created I am not being delivered markers that exist there when it is required.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#customPolygon') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #customPolygon
CREATE TABLE #customPolygon (geog GEOGRAPHY)



[![DECLARE @customPolygon  geography = 'MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.31260682058497 41.7828672412252, -122.66803538233832 41.74189213171878, -123.0157152218382 41.67409631073075, -123.35191487435746 41.58021595697532, -123.67306979164175 
41.461266240272025, -123.97583066087832 41.31852640120816, -124.25710598001243 41.15352132907401, -124.51409805934621 40.96800014522892, -124.74433194261869 40.763912348675035, -124.94567706168226 40.54338210199239, 
-125.11636173536279 40.30868123071627, -125.25498087780294 40.06220148128715, -125.3604974831004 39.80642653665781, -125.4322385960062 39.543904229883005, -125.46988656305209 39.277219329961135, -125.4734663894492 
39.008967205820475, -125.44333001234564 38.74172860785035, -125.38013825025583 38.47804574501649, -125.28484111194828 38.22039978159673, -125.1586570556347 37.971189832187214, -125.00305168962673 37.73271349727281, 
-124.8197163058454 37.50714895406215, -124.61054654308778 37.296538597688055, -124.37762139148631 37.102774215181654, -124.12318267532315 36.9275836675835, -123.8496150891857 36.772519052867715, -123.55942681226277 
36.638946322795874, -123.25523068653888 36.52803632929597, -122.93972591543192 36.44075727956827, -122.61568021845359 36.377868583149755, -122.28591236310895 36.339916078129036, -121.9532749859139 36.327228627297, 
-121.62063760871888 36.339916078129036, -121.2908697533742 36.377868583149755, -120.96682405639588 36.44075727956827, -120.65131928528895 36.52803632929597, -120.34712315956506 36.638946322795874, -120.0569348826421 
36.772519052867715, -119.78336729650465 36.9275836675835, -119.52892858034149 37.102774215181654, -119.29600342874002 37.29653859768806, -119.08683366598238 37.50714895406215, -118.90349828220107 37.73271349727281, 
-118.7478929161931 37.971189832187214, -118.62170885987955 38.22039978159673, -118.52641172157198 38.47804574501649, -118.46321995948216 38.74172860785035, -118.43308358237861 39.008967205820475, -118.43666340877571 
39.277219329961135, -118.4743113758216 39.543904229883005, -118.54605248872741 39.80642653665781, -118.65156909402486 40.06220148128715, -118.79018823646503 40.30868123071627, -118.96087291014557 40.54338210199239, 
-119.16221802920913 40.763912348675035, -119.3924519124816 40.96800014522892, -119.6494439918154 41.15352132907401, -119.93071931094948 41.31852640120816, -120.23348018018605 41.461266240272025, -120.55463509747037 41.58021595697532, -120.89083474998958 41.67409631073075, -121.2385145894895 41.74189213171878, -121.59394315124284 41.7828672412252, -122.31260682058497 41.7828672412252)), ((-119.1795222467484 42.50521242789702, -120.70099431758788 39.07636493660857, -115.32512633395542 38.91870544294517, -119.1795222467484 42.50521242789702)))'


    INSERT INTO #customPolygon
            SELECT geography::STPolyFromText(@customPolygon, 4326).MakeValid().ToString()
            UPDATE #customPolygon SET geog=case when geog.EnvelopeAngle() > 90 then geog.ReorientObject() else geog end
            SET @customPolygonJoin =  ' join #customPolygon poly on poly.geog.STIntersects(a.GeoLoc) = 1 '][1]][1]
```

I would like to avoid itemizing polygons within the multipolygon string as there could be an unlimited number.

I've tried ST unions and  ST difference, except it seems those require two geography inputs, where the multipolgyon is just 1.

TYIA

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this "hole" is artifact of your drawing tool. Within SQL Server, it is two overlapping polygons - so there is no hole, it is instead covered by both of the polygons.

But if you want to dissolve this into a single polygon, I would try to StUnion it with empty geography (`geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON EMPTY', 4326)`) or with itself.

Comment: You're right to a point. Essentially when dealing with multipolygon string (as opposed to multiple single polygon strings) a multipolygon becomes invalid when they intersect, and the makevalid() function essentially removes the intersect point from BOTH polygons rather than 1 of them, causing this void. To skirt around this, i essentially created a function that selects each polygon individually in a single polygon wkt and it then allows the overlap.